# NSMutableArray is nil when trying to use prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm a new developer and this problem has me scratching my head.

For whatever reason my punches mutable array remains nil while I'm trying to pass it over to to my DetailViewController. punches is a property in my Punches class of type NSMutableArray.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DetailViewController* dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [shiftTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
dvc.shiftPunches.punches = shifts[indexPath.row];
}
```

I have shiftPunches set as a property in my DetailViewController with a strong reference. Using the debugger my shifts mutable array shows that it has 2 objects (both mutable arrays).

I even tried:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DetailViewController* dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
dvc.punches.punches = [NSMutableArray new];
[dvc.shiftPunches.punches addObject:@"foo"];
}
```

and still get nil. I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What's `shiftPunches` is it allocated?

Comment: use `[NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: My guess is that `shiftPunches` has not been initialized, as @Larme mentions, so you're sending a `setPunches` message to `nil`. Please post your DetailsViewController code so we can see when and where you're initializing `shiftPunches`.

Comment: @davidf2281- you you guys are right, I'm not initializing shiftPunches. But I'm confused as to why I would want to initialize in my DetailViewController since I'm getting 'nil' before it even has a chance to complete the segue. Should this be initialized in my ViewController?

Answer (score -1):

If `pucnes` is valid NSMutableArray that is not nil, try do the following:

When you do - `[NSMutableArray new];` you just  create an empty array. Try do following:

1) Create NSMutableArray in DetailViewController. Name it `detailArray` (or something you like).

2) Then do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
dvc.detailArray = self.punches;


}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. When `prepareForSegue` is called, the segue that's passed in will have an instantiated instance of the destination view controller ready for use. Alloc-initing a new one and then immediately assigning its pointer to the destinationViewController will simply throw away the instance you've just created.

Comment: I edit my comment, please edit it if you can see mistakes. For my apps i always do this to pass values between controllers.

Comment: Still wrong. You've created a local instance of an object, `dvc`. As soon as this object goes out of scope -- ie at the end of the method -- it is thrown away and nothing else can ever reference it. Your code does nothing, except possibly create a memory leak if `self.punches` is strong.